# Flutter initState and dispose called twice during first build

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I've have an app with three screens. When I go from second screen to third screen. The initState of the third screen is called twice along with dispose.
Relevant parts of code :

**Screen 2**

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("Screen2: dispose");
    socket.io.disconnect();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

```
socket.on('start-resp', (_) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => GameScreen(
                    username: widget.username,
                  )));
    });
```

**Screen 3**

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("Screen3: dispose");
    socket.io.disconnect();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Screen3: init");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Screen3: Build");
```

**OutPut:**

```
Screen3: init
Screen3: Build
Screen3: init
Screen3: Build
Screen3: dispose
Screen2: dispose
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely what's going on:

```
socket.on('start-resp', (_) {
      print("MOST LIKELY I'M CALLED TWICE");
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => GameScreen(
                    username: widget.username,
                  )));
    });
```